My APK now considered as virus by Google Drive
I was using an old Android Studio and I decided to move to the latest stable one.
I had to rework all my apps to make them work with the gradle of the new Android Studio.
Bizarrely I now get the following message from Google Drive when I try to download some (not all!) of them:

"app.apk" is infected with a virus.


I've made sure that

Debuggable is false
Proguard is activated
App is signed properly with my keystore

Example of failing new AndroidManifest.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/finalicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    >

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SettingsActivity"  />
    <activity android:name=".SessionsActivity"  />

</application>

Example of failing new build.gradle.kts file:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.compose)
}
android {
    namespace = "com.example.gymtimer"
    compileSdk = 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.gymtimer"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 35
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
            isDebuggable = false
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)

    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation (libs.material)
}

Any idea of what could be wrong or how to debug it?

Further findings:

Virustotal reports a Trojan-Spy.AndroidOS.Banker via Google/Ikarus. NOT SURE WHY???!!! Is it a false report?
I created the default 'Hello World' app (by selecting 'File'-->'New Project...'-->'Empty Activity' in GUI), Google Drive reports it as a virus. I replaced composeBom to "2024.12.01" and Google Drive does NOT report a virus anymore. I did the same in my other apps but Google Drive still reports a virus. I then went back to my 'Hello World' app and replaced the gradle and toml by the ones from other apps and set composeBom to "2024.12.01". Google Drive does NOT report a virus.
I'm confused!


Have you tried uploading the APK to Virustotal and see what virus Google thinks that is in the APK? Based on the dependencies I don't see much possibilities for a malicious dependency but there is still a small chance that that virus message is true, e.g. if your development system is infected.

I would also suggest to scan the file using VirusTotal: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload

Virustotal reports a Trojan-Spy.AndroidOS.Banker via Google/Ikarus. None of the other vendors report anything suspicious.

I've added further findings to my post. Not sure how to progress with this.
